# How to get address of a struct object in python?

Tags: python, kernel

I am doing kernel module programming using ioctl calls to communicate between userspace and kernel space.
I plan on making the userspace api in python.

To pass data between kernel and userspace ioctl calls utilizes address, and data is copied using copy_to_user, or copy_from_user. The address here is given by `unsigned long arg`.

`int ioctl(struct inode *inode,struct file *filp,unsigned int cmd,unsigned long arg)`

In C userspace programming it is trivial to pass address.
What I want to do, is to use [struct](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) of python to create a structure which is compatible with the structure which i have defined in the kernel module, and pass the populated python struct, using ioctl from [fcntl](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html) module of python.

Is it possible?
If it is possible, how do i pass the address of python struct in the ioctl call?

I do not want to use ctypes, or extend python with c. Pure python code, is what i would like.

Comment: (+1) for using `[python]` and `[kernel-programming]` in the same question :)

Comment: Not sure why you "do not want to use ctypes", as this is exactly the task for which it was created!

Comment: Have you read the basics of `fcntl` ? Because it already does what you are asking for: ".. When the argument is a string it represents a binary structure, e.g. created by struct.pack(). The binary data is copied to a buffer whose address is passed to the C fcntl() call. ..". Anything else you wanna do ?

Comment: @Francis Avila: The source code of the module which i am working on, is very big, and I'm not the author. So its pretty hard for me to implement ctypes, redefining all the structures, etc. So basically, I just want to make structures on the fly, and pass it in the ioctl calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [fcntl docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html) show you examples how to do this. They use `struct` and `array`, but you can also use plain strings. If you pass a mutable buffer and `mutate_flag` is True, the actual backing buffer will be passed to the OS call. If it is unmutable, a copy will be passed and the resulting change in buffer will be returned by the call. See the documentation for [fcntl.ioctl()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.ioctl).

So you don't have to care about the address of the buffer backing the struct. Just pass it as a `struct` or `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the ctypes-module will help you here, especially [this section](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#passing-pointers-or-passing-parameters-by-reference)